# Id selector not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, click

I feel like I'm missing something very basic here.

I basically have 2 divs in the markup. When you click one (#x), the other one (#block1) acquires a new class (.change), and changes its color.

The only problem is the selector **("#block1")** inside the click function. If I replace the id of the first div with a class, it works fine. But using an id instead makes it invalid.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").click(function() {
    $("#block1").toggleClass("change");
  });
});
```

```css
#block1 {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: gold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#x {
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  right: -60vw;
  top: -15vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="x"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `block1` in your html?

Comment: nope just that one instance

Comment: The selector by `id` has a higher priority then `class` attribute.

Comment: Read about **CSS SPECIFICITY**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class, `.change`, won't override the background color set in `#block1` due to style precedence.

In this particular instance you would have to be more specific.

Change this:

```
.change {
    background: red;
}
```

To this:

```
#block1.change {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add #block1 along with your .change inorder to override background color given in #block1. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
   $("#x").click(function(){
     $("#block1").toggleClass("change");
   });
```

```css
#block1{
  width: 20vw;
  height:20vw;
  background:gold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#x{
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  right: -60vw;
  top: -15vw;
  cursor: pointer;
    }

#block1.change {
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">
   </div>

   <div id ="x">
   </div>
```

Comment: It would be good if you mention some words about CSS specificity. That is what OP is looking for.

Comment: I run the snippet, but first div is not red!

Comment: @Alexander You want the first div red only when you click on second div which is working in my snippet.

Comment: @Lavya R, I am sorry! I does not look onclick handler. +1

Comment: @Lavya R, I would be glad to do it, but the question is not my. I can voteup your answer only, and I already did it.

Comment: @Alexander Oops! I didnt check that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#x").click(function(){
     $("#block1").toggleClass("change");
   });
});
```

```css
 

#block1{
  width: 20vw;
  height:20vw;
  background:gold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#x{
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  right: -60vw;
  top: -15vw;
  cursor: pointer;
    }

#block1.change {
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">
   </div>

   <div id ="x">
   </div>
```

The reason is style given to `#block1` overwrites the style of `.change` class change your style to this

```
 #block1.change {
     background: red;
    }
```

Learn more about css priorities here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

Adding `red` background to specific id selector `#block1.change` is not good. In case, if you want to add `change` class on multiple elements, so you should overwrite your `background` property in `.change` class using `!important`(because css `#block1` has itself `background:gold`) like,

```
.change {
    background: red !important;
}
```

Snippet,

```js
$(function() {
  $("#x").click(function() {
    $("#block1").toggleClass("change");
  });
});
```

```css
#block1 {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: gold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#x {
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  right: -60vw;
  top: -15vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">
</div>

<div id="x">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `!important` to your CSS otherwise it's not overriding `gold` color:

```
.change {
  background: red !important;
}
```

So the whole code should be like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").click(function() {
    $("#block1").toggleClass("change");
  });
});
```

```css
#block1 {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: gold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#x {
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  right: -60vw;
  top: -15vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="block1">
  </div>

  <div id="x">
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">


  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use it and you should read properly css properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ok</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#block1{
  width: 20vw;
  height:20vw;
  background:gold;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#x{
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;

    }

#block1.change {
  background: red;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="x">
  asa
</div>
<div id="block1">
  aasds
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "#x").click(function() {

        $("#block1").toggleClass("change");

    });

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```